# Print out 2D array radios in Java

Tags: java, methods, printing, ascii, multidimensional-array

I am creating a Java Dungeon game and so far it imports a ASCII map into a 2d array. A player is then added and can roam around the dungeon using CLI. The player has to pick up all the gold before he can exit and win the game.

The problem I have is you can currently see the whole dungeon. For example..

```
###################
#.................#
#......G........E.#
#...........G.....#
#..E..............#
#..........G......#
#.............P...#
#.................#
###################
```

I would like it so you can use a `LOOK` command and see a 2 tile radios around the player. For example..

```
X...X
.....
..P..
.....
X###X
```

So far I have come up with this.

```
public void look(){
    try{
        System.out.print("X");
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX-2][posY-1]);
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX-2][posY]);
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX-2][posY+1]);
        System.out.print("X");
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX-1][posY-2]);
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX-1][posY-1]);
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX-1][posY]);
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX-1][posY+1]);
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX-1][posY+2]);
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX][posY-2]);
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX][posY-1]);
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX][posY]);
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX][posY+1]);
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX][posY+2]);
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX+1][posY-2]);
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX+1][posY-1]);
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX+1][posY]);
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX+1][posY+1]);
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX+1][posY+2]);
        System.out.print("\n");
        System.out.print("X");
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX+2][posY-1]);
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX+2][posY]);
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX+2][posY+1]);
        System.out.println("X");
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        System.out.println("AGAINST WALL....");
    }
}
```

I am sure there is a better way to do this but I can't figure it out. This method also only works unless the player is against a wall. Is there a better way to do this and how would I be able to create a buffer around my map of '?' for the tiles that are not in the map.

Comment: There are a lot of `System.out.print` statements. You could consider building the string using `StringBuilder`, then use one `print` statement. Also, you could use a nested `for` loop to build the string, then after the loops, write over your 4 corners with X's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as others suggested you should use 2 for loops. I've added the required logic get the result you're looking for

```
public void look()
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(25);

        for(int y= posY-2; y <= posY+2; y++){
            for(int x = posX-2; x <= posX+2; x++){
                try
                {
                    if(x<0 || y<0 || x > myWorld.length || y > myWorld[x].length)
                        sb.append("#");//Wall or outside map
                    else
                        if(Math.abs(posX-x)+Math.abs(posY-y) < 4)
                            sb.append(myWorld[x][y]); //Valid part of map
                        else
                            sb.append("X"); //Unreachable corner
                }
                catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){} //This shouldn't happen :)
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
```

Using StringBuffer will keep the execution time down with bigger amounts of data

Comment: This is great. However it prints it out side ways so `X...X
....#
.GP.#
....#
X...X` instead of `X...X ..G.. ..P.. ..... X###X`

Comment: Oh, Yeah, just iterate in the other direction. Easy to fix :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to add 2 variables, which would contain size of array (for example sizeX and sizeY) and use two cycles:

```
for (i = posX-2; i<posX+2; i++){
  for (j = posY-2; j<posY+2; j++){
    if (i>=0 && i<sizeX && j>=0 && j<sizeY){
     System.out.print(myWorld[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
void getSurrounding(myWorld, posX, poxY, width, height, radius)
{
  for(i=-(radius-1);i==(radius-1);i++)
  {
    if(i==0 || i==radius)
    {
      System.out.print('X');
    }
    if(posX+i>width)
    {
       break;
    }
    for(j=-(radius-1);j==(radius-1);j++)
    {
        if(posY+j>height)
        {
           break;
        }
        System.out.print(myWorld[posX+i][posY+j]);
    }
    System.out.println('\n');
}
```

}

```
//Call in your look function
void look()
{
    getSurroundings(myWorld,posX,posY,width,height,2);
}`
```

Comment: So here the radius is 2. So both the loops will run from -1 to 1... Since we need an X, at the beginning and at the end of each line, i am checking it in my first if condition. For the boundary conditions i am checking with width and height. I have not tried running this code. But i think the logic is correct.